# Can I display graphic characters in a terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminator, special-characters, emoji

I saw a couple screenshots showing some characters displayed as graphics, like this:

[image: command line interface with emojis]

While in my terminal I get this:

[image: missing character blocks]

How can I configure my terminal to display those images???

Comment: Terminator seems to use the same VTE implementation as Gnome Terminal, which recently added suopport frotando rendering these icons (Unicode Emoji). Maybe the VTE version used is not up to date.